# DateFormat.parse not working. Trying to find difference between two times

Tags: java, android, date-format

to find difference between two times, I have written this code but the date parsing is not working at all. 
Toast before the DateFormat.parse statement is shown but the one after that statement is not shown. I am not getting what the issue is. Can someone find any error in this code?
Thanks in advance.

```
private long findDelay(String currentTime, String startTime)
{
    //currentTime = "10:58 AM" and startTime = "9:28 AM"
    long diff=0;
    currentTime="6/1/16 "+currentTime;
    startTime="6/1/16 "+startTime;

    DateFormat format=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);

    try
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"before parsing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Date date1=format.parse(currentTime);
        Date date2=format.parse(startTime);
        Toast.makeText(this,"after parsing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        diff=date1.getTime()-date2.getTime();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return diff/60000;
}
```

Using SimpleDateFormat :

```
   private long findDelay(String currentTime, String startTime)
{

    long diff=0;
    //currentTime = "10:58" and startTime = "9:28"

    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    try
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"before parsing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Date d1 = format.parse(currentTime);
        Date d2 = format.parse(startTime);
        Toast.makeText(this,"after parsing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        diff=d1.getTime()-d2.getTime();

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return diff/60000;
}
```

Comment: Is the short date format on your device and locale definitely `d/M/yy`? Given that you've only got a time to parse, is there any reason you're not using `getTimeInstance`?

Comment: Actually I tried SimpleDateFormat also but then also, it works the same way.

Comment: *How* did you try `SimpleDateFormat`? If your format is always `H:mm a` why not use that?

Comment: Can you give me code to find difference between these times : time1 = 10:58  and time2=9:28 ?

Comment: I've already made a suggestion: try a date formatter with your specific format.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I tried SimpleDateFormat, but that also doesn't work. I have added that code also. Please check

Comment: Do you need to involve date when you are comparing two times within same day : `6/1/16` ?

Comment: Right, you've added code that wasn't what I suggested though. In fact I *should* have suggested `h:mm a`, but you tried `hh:mm`, which doesn't fit with "9:28" as a value. You should also log the exception, and include that detail in your question. Finally, the values seem to have changed between your two attempts - why? Do you *actually* have an am/pm indicator or not?